Error while trying to use "npx convex dev"
I have a Next.js App with TypeScript option. I integrated Convex to the setup using the docs next.js quickstart and everything went well. But, when I turned off the database server and tried to run npx convex dev I got the error shown in the image below.

I am using Convex Auth with SSA.
Package Details: 
Next.js - 14.2.13 
Convex - 1.16.2

Have you considered the error information saying This module cannot be imported from a Client component module and that push deployment failed? I tried replicating the error but could not. Could you please confirm if you have any written code apart from the setup?

No nothing apart from setup. Were you trying to setup Convex Auth which is actually in beta testing mode.

Yes, I made 2 setups: one with Convex Auth after noticing your statement I am using Convex Auth with SSA, and another just following the next.js quickstart guide. Could you please expatiate more on how you did your Auth setup with details on how to replicate?

Do you have middleware.ts file in the convex directory? It should be in src/.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
